# Django: Change default to True in Field.null or Field.blank

Tags: django, orm, model

I think Im missing it in documentation but just couldnt find. 
How can I set the default behavior of Field.null and Field.blank to True instead of False ? 
I just do not want to do that in each field declaration like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True)
```

I have many fields that the default is blank=True so I want to just:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   birthdate = models.DateField()
```

and the behavior would be the same than the first

Comment: Please, don't. Conventions are important. If another developer one days picks up your code, their expectation will be that any field without `null`/`blank` kwargs is False for those kwargs. All this does is create confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Derive a child class from `DateField` and override the keyword argument in the initializer.